# Unit test i18Next - TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, i18next

My code is working fine but i got problem to setup unit test and test it. I got error when there is a code using the i18next library, could anyone give some advise?

The below configuration is getting from [here](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing)

**Error**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
>
> ```
>    7 |  i18next
> >  8 |   .init({
>      |    ^
>    9 |     interpolation: {
>   10 |       escapeValue: false,
>   11 |     },
> ```

**Helper.tsx**

```
export function validation(controlName: string){   
    var messages = require('src/translations/i18next');
    var requireMessage=messages.t('required');
    //omit irelevant code
  }
```

**Helper.test.tsx**

```
test('Validation',()=>{
    expect(Helper.validation('My Name')).toBe('aaaaa');        
})
```

**mock-setup.js**

```
jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
    use: () => {
      return {
        init: () => { }
      };
    },
    t: k => k
  }));
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    'roots': [
      '<rootDir>/src'
    ],
    'transform': {            
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    'testRegex': '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',    
    'moduleFileExtensions': [
      'ts',
      'tsx',
      'js',
      'jsx',
      'json',
      'node'
    ],
    'moduleNameMapper': {
      '^src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
      '^components/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1'
    },
    'snapshotSerializers': ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],

    'setupFiles': ['<rootDir>/src/jest/setupEnzyme.ts',
    '<rootDir>/src/jest/mock-setup.js', 
  ],
     'moduleDirectories': ['node_modules', 'src']
  }
```

**i18next.tsx**

```
import i18next from 'i18next';

var common_en = require( "src/translations/en/common.json");
var common_es = require( "src/translations/es/common.json");

i18next
  .init({
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    lng: 'en', // 'en' | 'es'
    resources: {
      en: {translation: common_en},
      es: {translation: common_es},
    },
    debug: true,
  })

  export default i18next;
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [ "es2015","dom" ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "jsx": "react",   
      "sourceMap":  true, 
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "paths": {
            "src/*": ["src/*"],
            "components/*": ["src/components/*"]            
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `src/translations/i18next`?  (It looks like it calls `i18next.init(...)` and not `i18next.use(...).init(...)`)

Comment: update in the question, yes im using i18next.init. Do you mean that is not correct?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Anyone can give advise on this? I Still confused! The error gone after i change this line

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
```

to

```
import * as i18next from 'i18next';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should mock `i18next` like this:

```
jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
  init: () => {},
  t: k => k
}));
```

---

**Details**

The mock in the question is set up for using `i18next` like this:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';

i18next
  .use(...)
  .init(...);
```

Since you aren't using `.use` you can just mock `.init` directly.

Comment: Let me know if this info is enough to fix it.  You also might need to set `esModuleInterop` in your TypeScript config and change how you are requiring (I'm surprised you don't need to require `default` like this: `var messages = require('src/translations/i18next').default;`)

Comment: Still having the same issue after apply the solution you provided. even set esModuleInterop:true in tsconfig. updated question with tsconfig.json

Ya. is working fine without default